# Enable i2c on Ubuntu Mate Raspberry Pi 3

Tags: i2c, driver, ubuntu, servo

I am having trouble utilizing the i2c bus on my raspberry pi. I am attempting to use it through Adafruits python module for their Servo driver board. When I run a method using the i2c I get:

> IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/dev/i2c-1'

When I execute `i2cdetect -l` I get nothing.

When I execute `i2cdetect 1` I get:

> Error: Could not open file `/dev/i2c-1' or`/dev/i2c/1': No such file or directory

(The same happens with 0)

I have tried issuing the command `sudo modprobe --first-time i2c-dev`

To which I receive:

> modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'i2c_dev': Module already in kernel

The results of `journalctl | grep modules` are in the following image:

[image: journalctl | grep modules]

Comment: Also when the pi boots I get: 
" failed to start load kernel modules "

Answer (score 5):

Add the following line to `/boot/config.txt`

```
dtparam=i2c_arm=on
```

Add the following line to `/etc/modules`

```
i2c-dev
```

Reboot

Comment: This did not help. I still have the same exact errors as before.

Comment: Is Ubuntu Mate the IoT version?  Either way I don't use Mate and if it doesn't properly support device tree you are probably stuffed.

Comment: No, it is not the IoT version. Should I be using that? The reason I am using Ubuntu Mate is because I need to install ROS and I had too many issues trying to do that in raspbian jessie.

Comment: That is even odder, I could see IoT not being mainstream, but not Ubuntu proper.  It should work.  Perhaps ask on raspberrypi.org/forums (when it is back up) or a Ubuntu forum.  I'm afraid it is a cold hard fact that you will get the best support if you are using Raspbian.

Comment: Ubuntu MATE (at least the recent versions) uses Device Tree, and identical kernel and firmware to Raspbian.

Comment: If that is true, then what could be causing the issue that I am having. Better yet, what should I do to start diagnosing the issue?

Answer (score 2):

To enable i2C on the Pi3, do the following:

1. `sudo raspi-config`
2. Choose advanced options
3. Choose I2C Enable/Disable automatic loading
4. Follow the prompts to set this to load this automatically
5. Reboot the Pi

I'd recommend getting the `i2C` utilities too with:

```
sudo apt-get install -y i2c-tools
```

Use:

```
sudo i2cdetect -y 1
```

This will display a grid showing what address any devices are using on the i2C bus.

Comment: raspi-config is definitely not available for Ubuntu Mate the solution you posted is for raspbian. raspi-config is a front end for the /boot/config.txt file. The solution you posted would add dtparam=i2c_arm=on to /boot/config.txt and also remove i2c from the blacklists file if its listed. The answer posted by joan instructs this but also did not work for my pi.